# Properties of an object changing after calling 'await database' in Flutter?

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

This has had me stumped for a few days.
I am developing a simple gym tracking app, and am trying to save a workout to the database. When I call my saveWorkout(Workout w) function, the workout in full gets passed to the function, I have checked this by running it in debugger. After I call the line 'var dbClient = await database;' and then check the properties of the object, one of the properties (which is a list) goes from a length of 2 to a length of 0. The strangest thing is that the other properties of the workout (e.g. name) are not affected. The two print(w.name) calls both print out "TestWorkout" (what I named it).

```
Future<Workout> saveWorkout(Workout w) async{
    print("length before await: " + w.exercises.length.toString());
    print(w.name);
    var dbClient = await database;
    print("length after await: " + w.exercises.length.toString());
    print(w.name);
    w.id = await dbClient.insert("Workout", w.toMap());
    return w;
  }
```

The first print line prints out 2. The second print line after the await call prints out 0. What on earth could be going on?
I know everything to do with the database is okay as I have other objects that interact with it. Below is the code to connect to the database. Can anyone offer any insight?

```
Future<Database> get database async{
    if (_database != null)
      return _database;

    _database = await initDB();
    return _database;
  }

  initDB() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "TestDatabase.db");
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe on the line `w.id = await dbClient.insert("Workout", w.toMap());` try encoding your map to String with `jsonEncode`.

```
w.id = await dbClient.insert("Workout", jsonEncode(w.toMap()));
```